# Streaming data from kafka to http

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, akka-http

I'm trying to create a scalable pipeline that will *get* messages from Kafka and *send* them to multiple http endpoints.

What I've tried so far is a (plain Kafka) Consumer that consumes messages from Kafka topic and asynchronously sends them to an Endpoint using Akka-Http.
So the thing I have is a sort of Kafka-Connector.

Question: is it worth (and possible) to rewrite the application as a Kafka-Connector considering that the destination of messages is not static and may vary for each message.

Comment: https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/external/http.html Maybe that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the answer is no.  Apart from the various destination issue you mentioned, formatting and displaying of messages is quite application specific and cannot be delegated to a generic purpose connector.

Answer (score -1):

> is not static and may vary for each message

There is no reason you couldn't try [writing a SinkTask](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html#sink-tasks) that will parse and route a `SinkRecord` object into different HTTP routes.

The only benefit you might get is that you are abstracting away the plain KafkaConsumer API

Maybe use [kafka-connect-rest](https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest) as a starting point